# (INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY) in AndroidStudio with Moto EMDK

Tags: android, motorola

I'm using AndroidStudio to make some tests with an Motorola Solution (now Zebra Technologies) TC55.
Actual I'm trying to use the [EMDK (custom SDK to access the proprietary features)](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/community/android/emdk) to read some barcodes with the integrated scanner.
I just found many questions and answers but I don't use any functions of Google API or something else. I just integrated the library "com.symbol.emdk".

I followed the instruction from Motorola for AndroidStudio.
https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/community/android/android-forums/android-blogs/blog/2015/02/10/developing-emdk-apps-with-android-studio-10x

Now when I try to debug or start the application on my TC55 I get the following error:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: motorola_solutions-tc55-13357521650478
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Ausbildung\Uebungen\Applications\MotoSDKTest\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.iwr.smith.motosdktest
Installing com.iwr.smith.motosdktest
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.iwr.smith.motosdktest"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.iwr.smith.motosdktest
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]
```

I don't know how I can solve this problem.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running Android v4.1.1 on the TC55, you need to install the [EMDK runtime](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-2979) on the device, otherwise you're application will fail at install time for a missing shared library.

The runtime is already included in the KitKat (Android v4.4.3) OS that has just been released. [The AOSP version is already available](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=99139&productDetailGUID=17bba9494c7a0410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=2202caf8fb16e310VgnVCM1000000389bd0aRCRD) the GMS version will be released shortly.

Just remember that you need to upgrade to the [EMDK v3.1+](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-2281) to target TC55 with Android v4.4.3.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and awesome help!